# Extract all values in 3D image that fulfill certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, image-processing

Hallo I tried to extract some image points with (x,y,intensity) that fulfills (intensity > c) and return only (x,y,condition) as list sorted by the x value. The reason is that I want to get a mathematical model of the surface that is extracted from a floodfill image. [image] Now I want to derive the model. I used did I something wrong? or what are these values:

`np.extract(surface > 0, surface)`

result:

[  510.   510.   510. ...,  1020.  1020.  1020.]

I wanted something like list sorted by x value and the height. The intensity does not matter at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I still had a 3 channel image. I thought I would have a one channel image after thresholding.

Solution:

```
    surfacePoints = np.where(surface > 0) #np.where(condition)
    print(surfacePoints)
    x,y = np.take(surface, surfacePoints) #np.take(array,lists of indizes)
```